# How to wire new 3 way dimmer switch with continuous loop hot wire

Tags: wiring

Old switch has a loop wrapped around screw.  [red wire on brass screw]

[image]
New dimmer has 4 wires (no screws to wrap around).  How do I connect red wire (looped) to new black wire?  Do I cut red wire and use larger wire nut for 3 wires?

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm the red on the switch is the hot supply? On dimmers the red(s) are switched, and the black gets the hot. Regardless, to connect a looped wire with one from the dimmer, yes, you unscrew and then cut the loop open, add the other wire, twist them together and cap it with a nut.

Comment: Are you aware that you are replacing a 3-way switch?  Have you identified the travelers vs. the common?

Comment: To P2000 - Yes the red is confirmed to be hot on old original switch (first picture).  I will cut red hot loop and connect to black on the dimmer.  Great - this worked.  Thank you

To Harper - Yes I am aware this is 3 way switch (I included this in title of question).  I have confirmed hot vs travelers.

Comment: @CherylH Actually, you included that you had a new three way dimmer switch, not that the existing switch was a three way. Many new dimmers can handle both three way and single switches but are wired differently which was what Harper was getting at.  :-)

Comment: @P2000  You should type this up as an answer since it solved the OP's question. Hopefully, they will check mark it as selected.

Comment: @JACK done. Thanks for prompting.

Answer (score 3):

To connect a looped wire with one from the dimmer, yes, you unscrew and then cut the loop open, add the wire from the dimmer, twist them together, and cap it with a nut.

Just be sure: confirm that the red on the switch is indeed the hot supply and not a traveler or common. On dimmers the red(s) are switched, and the black gets the hot.